# Saving to a date / datetime field using SQLSAVE

Tags: r, sql-server, date

I'm using the following R code to save into database. However, the date field is not properly saved.

```
storedata$update = as.character(excelSerialNumToDate(tape$date),"%Y-%m-%d")
sqlSave(channel = dbhandle,dat = storedata,tablename = 'dbo.storeinfo',append = T,rownames = F,colnames = F,verbose = T,safer = F,fast = F, nastring = NULL)
```

What is the best way to save into a date field using `SqlSave` in R?

Comment: Why `as.character()`? If the SQL column is of the `date` data type why aren't you sending an R `Date`? If you must send dates in character format (which indicates a design problem) then you probably want to use `format(excelSerialNumToDate(tape$date), format="%Y-%m-%d")` instead.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, the issue is with SqlSave. Trying to understand how to format the dates for SqlSave.

Comment: When I debug and look at insert statement, the date is inserted without quotes (2020-02-07). How to inform SqlSave to insert each field with quotes surrounding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote my own SqlSave to eliminate these issues.